# SQL update in C# shows no errors but doesn't update aswell

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update

Here is a simple subtraction with 2 integers. The SQL Statement works but the value doesn't update in the database. Here is the code below.

```
var rest = antrag.Urlauber.RestUrlaub - antrag.Tage;
var sqlcom = "UPDATE Person SET RestUrlaub = " + rest +" WHERE ID = " + id +"";
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlcom);
```

Anyone got an idea what the problem might be?

Comment: This is dangerous code by the way, please go and read about SQL injection.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements) It's not just about *security*, but also *correctness*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query looks okay.

> The issue can be with your "id"

Execute the query manually on your database and see if it updates. If the id is wrong then the query returns success without updating anything.

Suggestion - Usage of queries like this are prone to very big security loopholes like SQL injection. Consider using ORMs like Entity Framework or pass query parameters as ADO parameters rather that stitching directly in query.

Optionally: if you didn't prefer to use big ORMs like Entity Framework, I've created a simple dapper based library that you can consider to run your queries in 1 or 2 lines safely.

How to use:  https://github.com/sangeethnandakumar/Express-Data-Library

Installation

```
Install-Package Twileloop.ExpressData -Version 1.0.0
```

Running a parameterized query safely to prevent SQL Injection

```
var sql2 = $ "SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE Id=@id AND Fname=@fname";
result = SqlHelper.QuerySafe<TblUser>(sql2, 
new 
{
    id = 1,
    fname = "Sangeeth"
},
_connectionString);
```

Comment: @Sangeethnadakumar  I have tested the query manually and it worked

UPDATE Person SET RestUrlaub = 3 WHERE ID = 4

Comment: Can you try running SQL profiler to identify if the query from your C# code is reaching your SQL server

Comment: I looked it up! It reached the profiler and showed this UPDATE Person SET RestUrlaub = '3' WHERE ID = 33. 

No wonder it doesn't update the ID 33 does not exist. Does this help?

Comment: Now the issue is in your program logic. Check how "id" variable populated. The question not explained or demonstrated how id variable is populated

Comment: Yeah. I swear this is probably a logic issue in getting the id. This answer explains it right.

Answer (score 0):

db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand returns an integer, you should try to print it to see what it returns, you might have an error executing this query : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand?view=entity-framework-6.2.0